# How can I rotate the data in a 2D n by n matrix by an arbitrary angle?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, matlab

[How to rotate a matrix by 45 degrees?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732679/how-to-rotate-a-matrix-by-45-degrees)

So I found this post where someone shows images of a 45-degree rotation of a matrix. I would like to do the same thing, but for 120 degrees (Or for any other angle). They go from 5x5 matrix to a 9x9 matrix which is fine, but how do you know where to add the zeros, and what the new size of the matrix will be given the size of the original matrix and the new rotation angle?

In short, I want to rotate the data in the matrix itself, thanks :)

Comment: I'm just puzzled, what would a $1^{\circ}$ rotation look like approximately ?

Comment: That's what I would like to figure out..I imagine the new matrix would be much, much larger than the original one because of the small angle..that is all I can guess

Comment: You can only rotate by an angle $\theta$ if $\tan \theta = \frac{a}{b}$ is a rational number. And then in your new rotated matrix previously adjacent values will be in cells that are offset by $a$ and $b$ rows/columns.

Comment: Ah I see, so 120 degrees wouldn't work, mind telling me how you figured this out?

Comment: Think of it backwards, starting with a rotated matrix. The cells containing the values will have some fixed offset (a,b) which means they lie on a line with slope $\frac{a}{b}$. This is at an angle $\tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{b})$ from horizontal. So that is the only kind of angle possible.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thanks!